# How to move select check boxes column to the end in Vuetify v-data-table?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Just starting with Vue and Vuetify, and have a simple question. 
I'm using `v-data-table` to display my data, and I'm using the default `v-model="selected"` and `show-select` props. By default, the checkbox column appears as the first column, but I need it to be the last column, how can I achieve that?

This is basically the Vuetify doc example, which is pretty much the same as mine:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    v-model="selected"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :single-select="singleSelect"
    item-key="name"
    show-select
    class="elevation-1"
  >

  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return 
        selected: [],
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'left',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
          { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
          { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 237,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,
            protein: 6.0,
            iron: '7%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 305,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '8%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 356,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,
            protein: 3.9,
            iron: '16%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 375,
            fat: 0.0,
            carbs: 94,
            protein: 0.0,
            iron: '0%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 392,
            fat: 0.2,
            carbs: 98,
            protein: 0,
            iron: '2%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 408,
            fat: 3.2,
            carbs: 87,
            protein: 6.5,
            iron: '45%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 452,
            fat: 25.0,
            carbs: 51,
            protein: 4.9,
            iron: '22%',
          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 518,
            fat: 26.0,
            carbs: 65,
            protein: 7,
            iron: '6%',
          },
        ],
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Put header (column) entry with `value: data-table-select` at the end of your `headers` array.

So for your example headers:

```
headers: [
  ...
  { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
  { text: '', value: 'data-table-select' }
]
```